# MVVMCross wont restore when running Nuget restore - Error: MvvmCross.Core' already has a dependency defined for 'MvvmCross.Platform

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, nuget, mvvmcross, azure-devops

I am trying to build my `Xamarin.iOS` application on my Mac using **Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online)** and the **VSTS Build Agent** (https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent)

When my `Xamarin.iOS` project comes to build it starts to restore the nuget packages and then errors with the following error:

> 'MvvmCross.Core' already has a dependency
>   defined for 'MvvmCross.Platform'.
>   'MvvmCross.Tests' already has a dependency defined for
>   'MvvmCross.Platform'. 'MvvmCross.Binding'
>   already has a dependency defined for 'MvvmCross.Core'.

I found this post on nuget [Error installing MvvmCross.HotTuna.MvvmCrossLibraries v4.0.0-beta1 in Xamarin Studio](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/1088)

which said that this may be caused by old nuget clients.

The current nuget client on my mac is **V2.8.6** so I upgraded the nuget client using

```
nuget update -self
```

which updated to **V3.4.4**

But now I am getting the error:

> MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '4.0' from
>   '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.4.0/lib/mono/4.5'.
>
> MsBuild.exe does not exist at
>   '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.4.0/lib/mono/4.5/msbuild.exe'.

Is this a bug with Nuget / MvvmCross or the VSTS agent?

Comment: That looks like a problem with the VSTS agent. Mono currently does not include an msbuild.exe. The VSTS agent should be looking for xbuild.exe in that location.

Comment: @MattWard I tried your solution outlined [here](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/147377/#Comment_147377) What do you think the problem could be with? Nuget, MvvmCross, or Xamarin?

Comment: That would not help. It is not a NuGet problem with the second error you are seeing. It looks to me like a VSTS configuration error since mono does not include msbuild.

Comment: @MattWard do you know where Xamarin should be looking for xbuild? I could try pass a custom path to xbuild in the VSTS Xamarin.iOS build task

Comment: On the Mac xbuild.exe is in the same location that VSTS is looking for msbuild.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the latest version of Nuget.exe to your repository and also add a shell script to execute it and restore Nuget packages on a Mac build server. The shell script would simply have a line similar to:

mono nuget/nuget.exe restore $1

The $1 is a parameter that is passed to the shell script and should point to the solution file you want to restore packages for. nuget/nuget.exe should point to the nuget restore file you added to the repository.

Then in VSTS instead of using the default Nuget restore task, add a shell script task and point it to the shell script in your repository and the parameter should point to the solution file.

Just make sure your build server can also find the mono command.

I wrote this post explaining the solution in more detail:

[Xamarin Build Services - Nuget Restore with VSTS](http://windingroadway.blogspot.com/2016/07/xamarin-build-services-nuget-restore.html)

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I ended up Refactoring out **MvvmCross** for [MvvmLight](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmLight/) and now it works.

This isn't the ideal answer as it took me about 2 and a half days to refactor out MvvmCross from my project. But the code feels a lot simpler now and I have managed to get rid of alot of complexity and...

**My Automated iOS build now works!**

In future I will be picking MvvmLight over MvvmCross as an Mvvm Framework

Answer (score 0):

Instead of upgrading the nuget to the latest version, please try to update the nuget addin for Xamarin to 2.8.7 by following the steps in this link: [Can I update the Nuget.Core.dll used by Xamarin Studio?](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/147377/#Comment_147377) which should fix your first problem. Nuget 3 has some issues on non Windows OS, check this page for details: [NuGet Compatibility](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/Compatibility)

Comment: I've tried the solution you posted. I have also tried it with a `Build Xamarin.ios` and a nuget restore pointing at the `packages.config` but neither work. Is this a problem with the VSTS agent?

Comment: For more information.. trying the fix in the first link gives the first error listed in my Question